# About learning the pro-étale topology *before* learning étale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Since "the pro-étale topology simplifies the introduction of $\ell$-adic cohomology in algebraic geometry" (tag 0966 on the Stacks Project), I wonder if it would be feasible to take B. Bhatt and P. Scholze's article *The pro-étale topology for schemes* as a first introduction to étale cohomology.

(I am in good terms with Hartshorne-level scheme theory and with derived categories.)

Comment: I guess you can read scholze and bhatt paper before reading about etale cohomology, if you are also comfortable with topos and sites, but it only simplify a small part of etale cohomology which is essentially of technical nature and people often just accept that the passage from cohomology with finite coefficients to l adic case work.so reading wonderful paper of scholze and bhatt is mostly orthogonal to learning etale cohomology of schemes

Comment: My guess is that there may be attempts in the future to build up étale cohomology in a pro-étale way from the start, but it's still the case that most theorems need to be proven in the finite coefficients case first. It has some conceptual benefits to do this, but I think it doesn't actually make proving e.g. the smooth and proper base change theorems easier.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Could you further explain some of the conceptual benefits you talk about? I am sorry if this is obvious but the finite coefficients case of the pro-étale topology is the étale topology?

Comment: In my opinion the main difficulty with this approach is that most foundational references on étale cohomology are written in the previous language and not in the pro-étale language so you would need to learn how to translate between the languages before you could read the proofs of any foundational theorem not in the Bhatt-Scholze paper. Learning both ideas simultaneously is probably worthwhile, but I don't think it's feasible to not learn at least something about the classical one.

Comment: To be blunt, you will not learn about the Kummer sequence of the cohomology of curves from Bhatt and Scholze's paper.

Comment: Echoing the comments by others, I wouldn't recommend it: that paper assumes knowledge of \'etale cohomology, and was written to clarify some technical points that come up in some advanced aspects of the theory. Moreover, most of the proofs of the "basic material" (e.g, proper base) proceed by reduction to the classical case (where we do not give the argument).

Comment: I guess I was only referring to the fact that in the end we usually care about $\ell$-adic coefficients instead of finite coefficients, and the pro-étale topology "does this right" from the beginning (instead of the ad hoc arguments using inverse systems). This difference becomes especially important when dealing with things like $\bar{\mathbf Q}_\ell$, as well as for setting up derived categories.

Comment: Do you understand etale cohomology with finite coefficients well? I don't think that part is simplified by the pro-etale viewpoint and it's already pretty non-trivial.

Comment: @Faris not yet. Thanks to everyone. It was very helpful!